# Calculating DAC samling rate from datasheet

Tags: datasheet, dac, sampling

I want to use the DAC121S101 DAC (attached) and was wondering if my sample rate calculations are correct.

Settling time is 10uS which means max sampling rate would be 1/10us= 100KHz, 100KSps

But need to look at digital side as well. Max clock rate is 30MHz and it is a serial interface. Need 16 bits for 1 sample so 1/30MHz * 16 = .53uS or 1.875Msps

So do I use the smaller rate of the two numbers above (100KSps vs 1.875Msps) which is 100KSps or do I need to divide 100KSps/16 = 6250Kps?

Thanks!
[DAC Datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/dac121s101.pdf?ts=1613753173749&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FDAC121S101%253Futm_source%253Dgoogle%2526utm_medium%253Dcpc%2526utm_campaign%253Dasc-null-null-GPN_EN-cpc-pf-google-wwe%2526utm_content%253DDAC121S101%2526ds_k%253DDAC121S101%2526DCM%253Dyes%2526gclid%253DEAIaIQobChMIlf33_rL27gIVDfnICh1J9QthEAAYAiAAEgJZgPD_BwE%2526gclsrc%253Daw.ds)

Comment: You're almost there.  Why do you think you need to divide the 100 KHz by 16?

Comment: I thought I saw an example and the person did it. Doesn't make sense

Comment: What kind of signal are you trying to generate with the DAC?  Is it just a simple sine wave?  A DC signal that changes relatively slowly (say, 1 Hz)?

Comment: The 10us is to get within less than 1/2 the LSB voltage.  Also it is for a very small load of < 200 pF.  If you drive a larger load you'll have to wait longer (12us for 500pF load).  Or if you don't care about all 12 bits of accuracy you could run it faster.

Comment: Yes, it will be a dc signal changing slowly.